# How do I compile SMPlayer?

Tags: package-management, compiling, qt

What do I need to install `qt` development libraries, so that I can then compile `smplayer`?

I can reasonably handle the C/C++ side of things, but I somehow always get lost whenever I try to set up a compiler/libraries, etc...

These instructions are from SMPlayer's Install.txt

> *Generic compilation
>
>          ---------------------------
>
>               You need at least Qt 4.3 to compile smplayer.
>
>               It won't work with an older version.
>
>               Be sure you have installed the Qt 4 development package.
>
>               Its name maybe qt4-devel, libqt4-dev or similar.*

Unfortunately, this doesn't say much to me for two reasons.

1. I simply don't know what "similar" means (eg. how can different packages be "similar"?)
2. `libqt4-dev`, as mentioned, is in the Lucid repository, but I got a slew of 17 *"unresolved dependencies"* messages when I marked `libqt4-dev` in Synaptic Package Manager.. (I thought the package manager automatically included any required dependencies) ... Here is one of the messages: *Depends: libqt4-script (=4:4.6.2-0ubuntu5) but 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu5.2 is to be installed*

I'm thinking to use `codeblocks` for the IDE (because I've used it in Windows ("from whence I came", and *ain't going back!* :) ... Aside from the issue of what to install, will I need to explicitly tell `codeblocks` about `qt`, or will it install to a known library path?

Comment: have you added a ppa with qt packages (kde repo etc) ?

Comment: Why do you want to compile it in the first place? You can install smplayer from the repos (`sudo apt-get install smplayer`).

Comment: @htorque: Why... because I want to make a minor mod to it, to suit a particular preference, which it doesn't offer...

Comment: @Alaukik: No I haven't added a ppa for qt packages... If I do need this can you put "how" in an answer.. thanks. (but why would I need a ppa if it is in the repository..)... or do you mean I should not have added a ppa?

Comment: Please add the whole output of `sudo apt-get build-dep smplayer` to the question.

Comment: @htorque: Alaukik's reference to ppa's got me looking at my repository settings, and this reminded me that I haven't noticed any updates coming through recently, so I checked, and all my update check-boxes were off (I turned them off *temporarily!!* 2-3weeks ago)... I set 'security', 'updates', and 'backports' - got my latest updates - tried the identical command `sudo apt-get build-dep smplayer`again (identical).. and it worked perfectly this time! .. I don't understand it... do you? ... And, do you still want to see the original (error) output?

Comment: There were updates to those packages in security and updates. I guess when you tried to install libqt4-dev it just couldn't find the updated packages and that's all. No, if it works I think we don't need any error output. Just create an answer so the solution is not buried in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from both htorque's and Alaukik's comments, I stumbled upon the fact that my updates have been turned off (for 2-3 weeks), and it seems that `qt` simply needed the latest updates, which of course weren't there... I installed the latest updates and qt installed fine... Thanks htorque and Alauik.